# if/else start the function again

Tags: ruby, if-statement

At the `else`, where the user didn't input a `1` or `2`, the script should start over again after displaying the error message. How can I do that?

```
    puts "Do you want to calculate celcius to fahrenheit (1) or fahrenheit to celcius(2)"
input = gets


if input == 1
    puts "Please enter degrees in Celcius."
    celcius = gets
    fahrenheit = (celcius.to_i * 9 / 5) + 32
    print "The result is "
    print fahrenheit
    puts "."
elseif input == 2
    puts "Please enter degrees in Fahrenheit."
    fahrenheit = gets
    celcius = (fahrenheit.to_i / 9 * 5) - 32
    print "The result is:"
    print celcius
    puts "."
else
    puts "Please enter option 1 or 2"
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap the entire thing [in a `while` loop](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_While_and_Until_Loops) and initialize the variable `input` to a value like `nil`.

The `while` loop's condition should check if the value is 1 or 2, and it will probably need to be converted to an integer with `.to_i` since `gets` will return a string.

```
# initialize to nil
input = nil

# Check if the current value (integer) is 1 or 2
while !([1,2].include?(input))
  puts "Do you want to calculate celcius to fahrenheit (1) or fahrenheit to celcius(2)"

  # Convert the string to an int after getting it as input
  input = gets.to_i

  if input == 1
    puts "Please enter degrees in Celcius."
    celcius = gets
    fahrenheit = (celcius.to_i * 9 / 5) + 32
    print "The result is "
    print fahrenheit
    puts "."
  # elsif here, not elseif!!
  elsif input == 2
      puts "Please enter degrees in Fahrenheit."
      fahrenheit = gets
      celcius = (fahrenheit.to_i / 9 * 5) - 32
      print "The result is:"
      print celcius
      puts "."
  else
      puts "Please enter option 1 or 2"
  end
end
```

In fact, rather than a `while` loop, using an `until` loop (which Ruby has unlike many other languages) is more readable when testing for a negative condition:

```
until [1,2].include?(input)
  ...
end
```

The `[1,2].include?(input)` is a slicker way of writing

```
 if input == 1 || input == 2
```

... that is easily expanded for additional values in the array.

Comment: Michael, incredible! That is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is it using a function.

```
puts "Do you want to calculate celcius to fahrenheit (1) or fahrenheit to celcius(2)"
def convert
    input = gets
    if input == 1
        puts "Please enter degrees in Celcius."
        celcius = gets
        fahrenheit = (celcius.to_i * 9 / 5) + 32
        print "The result is "
        print fahrenheit
        puts "."
    elseif input == 2
        puts "Please enter degrees in Fahrenheit."
        fahrenheit = gets
        celcius = (fahrenheit.to_i / 9 * 5) - 32
        print "The result is:"
        print celcius
        puts "."
    else
        puts "Please enter option 1 or 2"
        convert()
    end
end
```

If input != (2 || 1) could work too.